# accessing object inside array object java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm new to java, I did search for a solution and didn't found it.

I have "Trip [] _data" array of Trip objects.

"Trip" object is using "Date" class to represent the trip departure dates, Inside Trip class theres a boolean method "sameDepartureDate" that get a Trip object and done equalization, If it's got same departure day as this.object.

I have public method inside "Date" called "equals". Its getting Date object and done the equal to this.object.

The sameDepartureDate method inside Trip class are:

```
    public boolean sameDepartureDate (Trip other){
    if ((_departureDate.equals(other._departureDate)))
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

I need to check how many Trips inside the array is using the same departure dates.

in other words, if a given "Date object" is equals to the array[i] date object inside trip object. (using equals method from Date class, or using "sameDepartureDate" from Trip class)

How can i call a method from the Trip/Date class inside the array object to check with a Date object?

I tried to build a method like this, But I get an error "inconvertible types, Required: Date, found: boolean"

```
public int howManyTripsDeparture(Date date){
    //Setting default!
    int j=0;
    int i;

    if (date==null){
        return j;
    } 

    else for (i=0; i<_data.length; i++){  
            if (_data[i]==null){
                j=j;
            }
            else if ((Date) _data[i].equals(date)){ //here is the problem :/
                j=j++; 
            }
            else j=j;
    }
    return j;

}
```

It's homework, Therefor I cant build new methods inside Trip/Date class.

I can build new private methods as I wish inside the current class.

I cant figure out how to cast the _data[i] into a "Date" object??? I don't need the other data it's contained when I done the equalization.

Thanks for the help:-)

Comment: Can you post the whole `Trip` class?

Comment: _data[i] contains `Trip` and you can't cast it to `Date`

Comment: Yap, I got it, Thank you :-) Like Abu said, I did remove the `(Date)` casting and use the Trip method `getDepartureDate()` then `equals` it to the date object.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, just change this:

```
else if (_data[i].getDepartureDate().equals(date)){ //here is the problem :/
      j=j++; 
}
```

Just remove that `(Date)` casting that you are doing inside the `else if` because `if` requires a boolean inside the bracket

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but _departureDate is private inside Trip. is there other way of calling just the date object inside the _data[i]?

Comment: O.k! Thank you :-)) now it's working fine, but somehow I had to replace j=j++ with only j++, I have no idea why... :/  Any way thank you very much!!

Comment: you are always welcome, also because `j++` is same as `j = j+1`

Comment: 1. Thank you very much! 2. Yap j++ is the same as j=j+1, So I don't understand why when I used j=j+1 it's gave me the wrong results, and when j++ is used, it's producing the right results.